# dynamic_reconfigure group defaults

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I stumbled upon the not-quite-as-well-documented feature of [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) [groups](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic%20reconfigure/Reviews/7/1/11%20Groups%20API%20review%20API%20Review).

[As I understand](http://answers.ros.org/question/28327/dynamic-reconfigure-default-parameters/), whenever you set up a server, it should call the callback and initialize the config parameter with the values found in the cfg file. However, my groups are not being set to defaults, only my "bare" parameters are. If I change one of the group parameters, then the change takes effect.

Is there something I'm missing, or should I file a ticket?

(btw [this ticket](https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/issues/47) mentions inconsistent behavior, but it's talking about states rather than defaults, so I'm not sure it's related.)

```
void dynamic_cb(pkgConfig &config, uint32_t){
        a = Duration(config.a);
        b1 = config.groups.b.part1;
        b2 = config.groups.b.part2;
}
```

cfg file:

```
gen.add("a", double_t, 0, "a_description", 1, 0, 10000)
group = gen.add_group("b")
group.add("part1", double_t, 0, "b1", 3.0, 0.0, 10.0)
group.add("part2", double_t, 0, "b2", 3.0, 0.0, 10.0)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213305/dynamic_reconfigure-group-defaults/) by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3562 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ffurrer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3149/ffurrer/) on 2016-06-07**:
any update on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I figured it out :).

In the current implementation the generated `<name>Config` class contains the variables of all groups as members directly. The ones under the corresponding group (class), the ones you (and I as well) accessed, never get assigned the default values.

So what you should do instead (at least until this code gets cleaned up):

```
void dynamic_cb(pkgConfig &config, uint32_t){
  a = Duration(config.a);
  b1 = config.part1;
  b2 = config.part2;
}
```

You can take a look at the implementation of the code generator [here](https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/tree/master/src/dynamic_reconfigure).

Just adding this small note here: you can also not add parameters with the same name to different groups, as they would get the same variable name in the main `<name>Config` class.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [ffurrer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3149/ffurrer/) with karma: 115 on 2016-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2